# How do I detect if the system time is changed? (from .net)

Tags: .net, windows, time

I am using DateTime.UtcNow to measure time in my software and need to be able to tell if “action a” happens less more than 10 seconds after “action b”

However what if the system time is change?  So how I do I detect if the system time is changed?

I don’t wish to use a stopwatch as we need to run on servers with more then one CPU, see http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html

I also need to cope with virtual machines being paused and restarted, so the “tick count” is unlikely to be useful to me.

Comment: Not so sure that makes sense, a TimeSpan isn't affected by a clock change.  Daylight saving time and time zone changes are cached, they don't affect UtcNow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`SystemEvents.TimeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx) event to detect the time changed.  However, this will only fire if you have a messagepump running - this is fine for windows client applications, but not so much for most server applications (like services, web apps, etc).

Otherwise you can use [`Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) - it doesn't have excellent resolution, but if your "10" seconds can be "nearly 10 seconds" you're probably fine. A far as the VM limitation, note that TickCount rolls over when the machine has been up long enough, so you'll have to handle that, possibly with a `DateTime.UtcNow` sanity check either way.

I'd use the combination of both - but note that there's no absolutely accurate way other than checking some external timeserver that is known accurate (which is going to have perf impact) that will work in the VM case anyway... make sure you determine what is "reliable enough" before you spend more time than the issue is worth.

Answer (score 4):

I would still suggest using `StopWatch`.  If the problem described in [Beware of QueryPerformanceCounter](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=106) still exists, you're only talking a difference of a few milliseconds.  If you're worried about negative times (something I've never seen, and I use `StopWatch` a lot to time some pretty small intervals), then treat anything between -1 millisecond and -1,000 milliseconds as zero.

Using `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow` for any kind of timing is going to cause you trouble if somebody changes the date/time on the machine.  You have to use something that's completely internal to the computer and can't be changed.  `StopWatch` is the most reliable one I've found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TimeChanged event of the SystemEvents class to detect changes to the system clock at runtime:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx

This relies on your application having a message loop (I assume because the WM_TIMECHANGED message needs to be processed) so you will need a hidden form if it is a headless application e.g. windows service.

As for detecting changes to the system clock whilst your application is suspended because of being on a suspended virtual machine - well all bets are off really for a truly reliable solution. You could periodically record the last time you performed a check, and just ensure that time has not gone backwards. It is likely to take longer than ten seconds to suspend and resume a VM anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would compare system time difference with a monotic clock between 2 time intervals.  If the difference is bigger than some tollerance than someone changed the date and time on your machine