# how to record timezone changes using MSDN functions in windows when application is running

Tags: c, timezone

I'am working on C code.Do we have any MSDN function that records timezone changes when the application is running...

If MSDN function is not available,can anyone please provide any Microsoft link which states that timezone changes cannot be recorded while application is running......

Comment: is there any handler function in c (provided by MSDN) which can capture this event.

Comment: What do you mean by an "MSDN Function"?

Comment: i mean is there any windows API, that can be used to capture the system time change event.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net, you can subscribe to the [SystemEvents.TimeChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx).  This is the same as monitoring for the Win32 [WM_TIMECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

You should also see these related questions and their answers:

- [Is there a way to detect if the system clock has been changed backwards in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852209)
- [How do I detect if the system time is changed? (from .net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246882)
- [Detect manual time change and daylight savings time events in windows events log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139475)

Comment: how to use WM_TIMECHANGE in the windows service application.do we have any link.Since WindowProc is a function but not an handler.should we call this function at regular intervals to inspect system time change event?